# How can I get back my privilege to create a new database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, privileges

I log in PhpMyadmin with the root user,there is a red message

> No Privileges
>   under 
>   create new database,

How can I get back my privilege to create a new database?

Comment: Could you post the command you're trying to create the new database with?

Comment: He is using phpmyadmin..

Comment: he's obviously trying to do `CREATE DATABASE`, what else?

Comment: @Jacob, I thought maybe it was a crazy syntax error.  But this question looks suspiciously like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874653/i-accidentally-dropped-my-mysql-database-in-phpmyadmin-is-there-a-possibility-to ; I move to close.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cPanel, you have to create the database using cPanel, not phpmyadmin.